# Primary Key с использованием new

Tags: c#, ado.net

Объясните, пожалуйста,

```
customers.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { customers.Columns[0] };
```

В строке 54 немного странный синтаксис. Ключ накладывается на первый столбец массива? Но почему не записать как имятаблицы.имястолбца зачем обязательно как массив записывать? И причем здесь new?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// 

namespace CBS.ADO_NET.TableConstraints
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True;"; // создание строки подключения

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable customers = new DataTable("Customers");
            DataTable orders = new DataTable("Orders");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand customersCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerNo, LName, FName, Address1, Phone FROM Customers", connection);
                SqlCommand ordersCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderID, CustomerNo, OrderDate FROM Orders", connection);

                SqlDataReader ordersReader = ordersCmd.ExecuteReader(); // получение DataReader для таблицы OrderDetails

                // метод LoadWithSchema позволяет на основе объекта DataReader создать объект DataTable 
                //с ограничениями для столбцов как в базе данных и заполнить эту таблицу данными
                orders.LoadWithSchema(ordersReader);
                ordersReader.Close();

                SqlDataReader customersReader = customersCmd.ExecuteReader();
                customers.LoadWithSchema(customersReader);
                customersReader.Close();
            }

            // объект DataReader не имеет информации об ограничениях объектов DataTable, таких как 
            // UniqueConstraint, ForeignKeyConstraint и PrimaryKey, поэтому прийдется их создать вручную
            customers.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { customers.Columns[0] }; 
            ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { customers, orders }); 

            // создание ограничения ForeignKeyConstraint для таблицы OrderDetails
            var FK_CustomersOrders = new ForeignKeyConstraint(customers.Columns["CustomerNo"], orders.Columns["CustomerNo"]);
            orders.Constraints.Add(FK_CustomersOrders);

            parentGridView.DataSource = customers; // связывание элемента управления parentGridView с таблицей Products
            childDataGridView.DataSource = orders; // Связывание элемента управления childDataGridView c таблицей OrderDetails
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataTable.PrimaryKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.primarykey?view=netcore-3.1) принимает массив столбцов, а не столбец, потому как первичный ключ таблицы может состоять из нескольких столбцов.

Поэтому при присвоении свойству значения создается массив типа `DataColumn` с единственным элементом. Его здесь объявили как можно более явно для наглядности, можно было и короче:

```
customers.PrimaryKey = { customers.Columns[0] };
```

В качестве столбца указан первый столбец таблицы `customers`, т.е. столбец с индексом 0. Можно было бы и указать столбец по имени.

```
customers.PrimaryKey = { customers.Columns["CustomerNo"] };
```

Answer (score 0):

В чём тут сранного я не пойму.

```
customers.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { customers.Columns[0] };
```

Создание и инициализация массива типа DataColumn; почитайте [тут](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm#:%7E:text=same%20memory%20location%20%E2%88%92-,int%20%5B%5D%20marks%20%3D%20new%20int%5B%5D%20%7B%2099%2C%2098%2C,elements%20are%20initialized%20to%200.)

а то что `customers.Columns[0]` так это их выбор.

Захотели первый зная что там ключ, если вы знаете что ключ в правом кармане будите ли вы искать его в левом?

Comment: Подскажите, если использовать следующий синтаксис то где указать наименование столбца table.Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(column1, true));